# Error : Failed to create provisioning profile when I want to create an Archives (to generate an ipa)

Tags: swift, xcode, provisioning-profile

I try to create an ipa file but I have those errors I don't understant what it expect to me. Why this error pop ?
Then when they talk about `There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it.` I don't understand what I should do and where do it ? In apple developer account, on https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/ , I tried to go on Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles but they say it is for members (who paid I think).

Can you help me an tell me what I can do to resolve this problem and create the archives.
Thanks for your help and have a nice day.

PS : The complete errors :

````
There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it. ```

``` No profiles for 'gisgo.OazenIOSProject' were found
Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'gisgo.OazenIOSProject'. ```
````

Comment: the certificates to create the ipa are only available pay developer account and you need first try your app in a real device (register device in your account) and then you can create the ipa with the pay certificates, why? because I suppose that you want to import the app

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to put the ipa in install on Air to habe a link to download the app. It is only possible with a pay account ? If i have one pay account it will do it automatically or I should do others step ?

Comment: yes, its only possible with pay account, there are a lot kind of certificates, please read this article [apple developer program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/)